# Crystal report Memory Full .. Not Enough memory for operation

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am building a report using Crystal Reports . my report is pictures when i print i get this error
Memory Full .. Not Enough memory for operation

```
   PrintView frm = new PrintView();
        MainCryRep = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = DbPath + "\\Reports\\AllPicterCustmchild.rpt";
        frm.crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[0].ConnectionInfo.Password = "ad44pop";
        frm.Show();
```

Comment: Where do you see the message? Does it throw an exception? May you get the stack trace?

Comment: Where do you see the message? When load report -Does it throw an exception?NO